# Event upon initialization complete in WPF/Prism app

Tags: wpf, prism

In non-Prism WPF app, if I want to run code after initialization (e.g. execute the task specified by command-line argument), I can do it in `Loaded` event of the main window. However with Prism, the modules are initialized after main window is displayed, that is, `IModule.Initialize()` is called after `Bootstrapper.CreateShell()` and `Bootstrapper.InitializeShell()`. In this case which event/override should I use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The last thing called by `UnityBootstrapper.Run(bool runWithDefaultConfiguration)` is `InitializeModules()` (well apart from a call to Logger.Log).  So overide Run(...).

```
class Bootstrapper : UnityBootstrapper
{
    ...
    public override void Run(bool runWithDefaultConfiguration)
    {
        base.Run(runWithDefaultConfiguration);

        // modules (and everything else) have been initialized when you get here
    }
}
```

Comment: This is true, except for when you perform a `RequestNavigate` to get to your initial view, and you are relying on the container to resolve the object graph of that view. In that case that view is resolved sometime after the `Run` method finishes. The solution in that case is to call `RequestNavigate` after `base.Run`, and, for reasons I don't understand, put the lines `var regionManager = Container.Resolve<IRegionManager>(); var regions = regionManager.Regions["theRegion"];`